# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: object, null, typeerror, undefined

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at companion-bubble.js:1465:19726
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Ln (companion-bubble.js:1465:19144)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LGkh.png)

I need solution. Please help me anyone?

Answer (score 27):

Uninstalling the chrome extension loom would solve the problem.

Comment: 100% this! Loom was the issue here. Both a React JS Minified Error and the above one also.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Anahit's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74928337/7733418) you can also disable the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enter the Loom extension with the help of Google or Slack and solve the error.